# How to determine whether a given word comes between two other words?

Tags: java

For simplicity, let's say that I have two sets of words, sorted into alphabetical order. One set starts at "aardvark" and ends at "melon", and the other starts at "melon" and ends at "zebra". The word "melon" appears in both sets.

If I were to take an input word, say "banana", what would be a good (and efficient) way of determining which set of words it should belong to? Note: this isn't a question about whether the word "banana" already exists in one set, but rather a question about how to determine which set the word *should* exist in.

If there is an algorithm that someone knows, great. If they can provide some version in Java, even better!

Edit: Should also point out, whilst my example only has 2 sets, I want the algorithm to work with n sets.

Comment: should exist in based on what?  category?

Comment: In your example, is `"melon"` (or whatever word) always the last item in the first set? If so, this is as simple as checking to see if word `w` comes before the last item of the first set (which is `"melon"` in your case). Assuming you mean in sorted order. Generalized out, you just need to check each set to see if that word comes before the last item in the set, and then determine if it is before or after the first item. If it doesn't come before, it belongs in that set.

Comment: @GarrettHall - No, based on alphabetical order.

Comment: @birryree - Yes, melon is always the last word. However, I only have 2 sets for simplicity. I want to know an algorithm for n number of sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**For two sets:**

If `word` is your word (e.g. `"banana"`):

```
int cmp = word.compareTo("melon");
if (cmp < 0) {
  // it belongs to the first set
} else if (cmp > 0) {
  // it belongs to the second set
} else {
  // the word is "melon"
}
```

**For `n` sets:**

Place the dividing words into an `ArrayList<String>` (call it `dividers`) in alphabetical order:

```
ArrayList<String> dividers = new ArrayList<String>();
//... populate `dividers` ...
Collections.sort(dividers);
```

Now you can use `Collections.binarySearch()` to figure out which set the word belongs to:

```
int pos = Collections.binarySearch(dividers, word);
if (pos >= 0) {
  // the word is the divider between sets `pos` and `pos+1`
} else {
  int num = -(pos + 1);
  // the word belong to set number `num`
}
```

(Here, the sets are numbered from zero.)

Comment: Ok, but what if there are more than 2 sets? Sorry, forgot to add that to the original question. I only used 2 sets for simplicity, but my actual program will have many sets, all sorted alphabetically. So for instance:

aardvark - apple, apple - banana, banana - crime, crime - dog, ...etc

Comment: @Rsaesha - what happens when the word is equal to the last word in the set?

Comment: @birryree - If it's equal to the last word in the set, then both that set, and the set after (if it exists) should be returned.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have `n` sets.  Construct a list of the "partition" words in sorted order.

Then the set it belongs to is simply:

```
List<String> partitions = Arrays.asList("melon", "strawberry");
int setIndex = -(Collections.binarySearch(partitions, "banana")) - 1;
```

This works because [`Collections.binarySearch`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch%28java.util.List,%20T%29) returns the insertion position (-1) if it cannot find the key in the list.  If it might collide with one of the partition words then you should first check whether the result is negative.

### Edit

I edited to remove the requirement for the "book-end" values ("aardvark" and "zebra") as they actually only complicated things.

Answer (score 0):

Just check the first letter and see if it's between (first letter of set 1) and (first letter of last element of set 1). If it's equal to both first letters, move on to the second letters. If it doesn't fit in that set move to the next set. This is BigO(n*m), where n is the number of sets and m is the number of letters in your input word. Not too bad IMO.

Answer (score 0):

```
String mid = firstList.get(firstList.size()-1);
assert(mid.equals(secondList.get(0)));
if(newString.compareTo(mid) < 0) // belongs in first
else // belongs in second.
```

Obviously, you may need to adapt some of the method calls depending on how you're holding them.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [binary heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap) to store the lists then determining where to insert a word will take O(log n)

Answer (score 0):

```
    final int n = 99; // whatever

    final SortedSet<String>[] allMySets = new SortedSet[ n ];

    // put your sets into allMySets, no particular order required.

    final String searchWord = "banana";

    int i;

    for ( i = 0; i < allMySets.length; i++ ) {

        final SortedSet< String > ss = allMySets[i];

        if ( searchWord.compareTo( ss.first() ) >= 0 && searchWord.compareTo( ss.last() ) <= 0 ) {
            System.out.println("Word " + searchWord + " belongs to set #" + i);
            break;
        }

    }

    if ( i == allMySets.length ) {
        System.out.println("No matching set found.");
        // Maybe handle border case here...
    }
```